# React Native getItemAsync Returns Promise

Tags: react-native

I am writing a storage class as such:

```
//Fallback if SecureStore fails
let data = {};

import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

const Storage = {

    set: async function (key, value) {
        try {
            console.log("Setting Item");
            console.log(key);
            console.log(value);
            return await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
        } catch (e) {

            //fallback if set cookie fails
            data[key] = value;


        }
    },
    get: async function (key) {

        try {
            console.log("Gettimg Item");
            console.log(key);
            let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);

            if (result) {
                return await result;
            }

            return null;
        } catch (e) {

            console.error(e);

            value = data[key];

            return value;
        }
    }

export default Storage;
```

And Storage.set is called as such:

```
function() {

   Storage.set("some_key", "some_value");
}
```

And here is an output of the console.log

```
Setting Item
user_id
4ce9dse7-650a-4ff5-955d-466a640de2c4
Setting Item
user_first_name
John
Setting Item
user_last_name
Doe
```

So apparently the items are being set. But each time I use the get function `Storage.get(x)`, I get a promise back:

```
Promise {
  "_A": null,
  "_x": 0,
  "_y": 0,
  "_z": null,
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am using await twice but still returns a promise.

Comment: Could you include the code where you call your `Storage.set`?

Comment: I updated an example of set being ussed.

Comment: why are you awaiting for result when it found? Try to comment out this extra step, and before clean all of your async storage .. I mean start from clean-slate ... and you should also have `await` for `Storage.get(yourKey)` --> `await Storage.get(yourKey)`

Comment: ++ you should `await Storage.set(...)`, before calling `await Storage.get(...)`